# Установка прокси для телеграмм бота pyton

Tags: python, бот, прокси

```
import telepot
token = "..."

telepot.api.set_proxy('http':'http://52.157.177.98:80')
bot = telepot.Bot(token)

response = bot.getUpdates()
print(response)
```

Ввожу прокси так и так ('http://52.157.177.98:80'). Выдает ошибку (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request'))). Подскажите что делать.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что выбранный вами прокси не работает, проверить можно следующем способом

```
curl --proxy 52.157.177.98:80 check-host.net/ip
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

curl --proxy 103.52.188.144:80 check-host.net/ip
103.52.188.144
```